# In spring data jpa find by date could not working properly, because table date filed data type is timestamp

Tags: spring-data-jpa

In spring data jap find by date could not working properly,beacuase  in data base 'bookingDate' data type is timestamp without timezone(Postgre SQL), I need find by date avoid time of the column

Domain

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOKING")
public class Booking extends AbstractAuditingEntity {

ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID")
private Book book;

@Column(name = "SEAT_NO")
private String seatNo;

@Column(name = "BOOKING_DATE")
private Date bookingDate;
```

Repository

```
 public interface BookingDAO extends JpaRepository<Booking, Long> {

 Booking findFirst1BySeatNoAndBookingDateOrderByBookingDateDesc(String seatNo, Date date);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Temporal`, it will do you want.

```
Booking findFirst1BySeatNoAndBookingDateOrderByBookingDateDesc(String seatNo, @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) Date date);
```